# reactjs image upload memory full

Tags: android, reactjs, google-chrome, webview

[image]

the image show from chrome devtool how reactjs is collect images without delete it even after route
the images are keep collect there , when i run the app on computer i dont see any problem but in android webview the memory is getting realy fast to max ram and crush the app.

can i tell react not to save or to clear this memory